# Disable multiple instance of fragment

Tags: android

In my main activity when user clicks button it shows him specific fragment. But if he clicks it again it adds another instance to backstack. And then the user needs to click back many times as click on the button.

```
class AppActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app)

    SharedPreferenceHelper.init(this)
    GRPCClient.init(this)
    DataBaseHelper.init(this)

    imageViewDot.setOnClickListener {
        findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragmentApp).navigate(R.id.syncFragment) 
    }
}}
```

How can I prevent it from happening. What I need to do is if fragment is visible the button will not do anything.

Comment: https://github.com/sunil-singh-chaudhary/Fragment-Nested-Child-Backpress

Answer (score 0):

try to flag that you already added this fragment and don't do that again

```
class AppActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var navigated: Boolean = false

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app)

    SharedPreferenceHelper.init(this)
    GRPCClient.init(this)
    DataBaseHelper.init(this)

    imageViewDot.setOnClickListener {
        if(navigated) return
        findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragmentApp).navigate(R.id.syncFragment)
        navigated = true
    }
}
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed() // removes from back stack if present in there
        navigated = false
    }
}
```

or you can use `getBackStackEntry` or `getCurrentBackStackEntry` from `NavController` instance to check that this `Fragment` is already on the position